# How to get rid of padding added automatically to div vertically?

Tags: css, text, padding

I think this padding is always added to all elements, but it is inconvenient for vertical margin calculation because of this padding.
I want to get rid of this padding. What should I do?

```css
div { background-color:DodgerBlue; }
```

```html
<div>ABCDE</div>
```

## result

[image: qwdqwdqwd]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you want to do that, but anyways, you can use `line-height` to get rid of the extra spacing at the top and bottom

```
div {
  background-color: DodgerBlue; 
  line-height: 12px;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/dubuyimohi/1/edit) | [**Demo 2**](http://jsbin.com/figiquraqi/1/edit) (with `font-size`)

Comment: Why is there that extra bit of spacing at the top and bottom?

Comment: Thank you. :) Is there a way to get all the elements to work like this, without having to calculate one by one?

Comment: @leftclick You can define `line-height` on `body`, this won't be same for other tags like `h1-h6`, for example: https://jsfiddle.net/Lpurrad2/ so you need to set a different `line-height` for such elements

Comment: @OnelHarrison default `line-height` of the browsers is around 1.2 times the `font-size` hence the issue

Comment: Thank you. To tell you why I wanted to do that.. It was annoying to consider the space above when calculating the margin with the above element. :)

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the spacing on top and bottom of the text as your text is smaller than the containing container. Its actually not a padding (At least padding in terms of CSS).

You could either increase the line height of the text so that the text occupies more space and fits the container, or you could increase the font size to achieve the same.

```css
div { 
  background-color:DodgerBlue; 
  line-height: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div>ABCDE</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer :)